# Kendo observable checkbox not updating through jQuery .prop("checked")

Tags: jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

I've got a Kendo observable object that is bound to a number of checkboxes. When I update the checkboxes by clicking them, the observable object is correctly updated. However, if I update the checked state through code, the observable object is not updated.

A sample snippet is below and I've got a [Kendo UI Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UMoVU). When you click the Red, Green, or Blue checkboxes, the correct information is displayed in the box; however, if you use the "Select All" option, the observable object is not updated.

How can I correctly write the code for the "Select All" checkbox so the observable object is updated along with the checked state?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colordata = null;
    colordata = kendo.observable({
        colors: []
    });
    kendo.bind($("#chkbox-options"), colordata);
    
    colordata.bind("change", function(e) {
        var selectedColors = '';
        
        $.each(colordata.colors, function(key, value){
            selectedColors = selectedColors + " " + value;
        });
        if(colordata.colors.length == 0){
            $("#selected").val('no colors selected');
        }else{
            $("#selected").val('selected colors:' + selectedColors);  
        }
    });    
    
    $("#all").on("click", function() {
        $("#chkbox-options input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<input id="all" type="checkbox" />
<label for="all">Select All</label>
<div class="k-group" id="chkbox-options">
  <label for="chk1">Red</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="Red" data-bind="checked: colors" />
  <label for="chk2">Green</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="Green" data-bind="checked: colors" />
  <label for="chk3">Blue</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" value="Blue"  data-bind="checked: colors" />  
</div> 
<input id="selected" style="width:100%;" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is you are using property change, jquery prop method doesn't trigger colordata change event, [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/change/) explains:

> For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus

So instead using `prop()`, you should use `click()` method. [fixed dojo 1](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/OBuna)

Another approach you could use `trigger("change")` after use `prop()`. [fixed dojo 2](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/EQUBO)

Comment: Something similar with the `click()` method may work but your dojo doesn't work correctly. It just toggles the children checkboxes, it should either select them all or deselect them all. If you can fix the dojo I will accept this answer.

Comment: ah, i miss that part.. But i thought you could solve that by yourself. :D
I have fixed it, please revisit my dojo link

Comment: Yeah I could have fixed it by myself, I just thought the answer was incomplete without the fix.